# How to improve performance of LDAP Search Filter for User Hierarchy

Tags: java, search, filter, ldap, ldap-query

I want to search the Reporting hierarchy of a given CN and by using Manager attributes, in a downward direction in LDAP. Can anyone help us to know if there is any performant way of achieving this with the LDAP Search filters in Java? I tried searching different posts but couldn't find an answer.

```
Ex:
-Dept Head(input CN) - -Level 3 User
--Manager 1 -Level 2 User
---Member 1 -Level 1 User
---Member 2 -Level 1 User
--Manager 2 -Level 2 User
---Member 3 -Level 1 User
---Member 4 -Level 1 User
--Manager 3 -Level 2 User
---Member 5 -Level 1 User
---Member 6 -Level 1 User
```

In the above example Level 3 Users CN would be input and we should retrieve all the users below him till Level 0(all level Managers and Members) of the given CN.

IF input CN is Level 1 users CN

- Output will include all Level 0 reports below Level 1 User(input CN)

IF input CN is Level 2 users CN

- Output will include all Level 1 and Level 2 reports below Level 1 User(input CN) ... and so on

Right now I am generating a filter for each level dynamically and searching using that filter in the below level. If there are more levels, the search is taking time to return the expected results.

My Code

```
protected static ArrayList<ValueCollection> getUserReportsTreeDetails(String accountName, String initial,
            String url, String principal, String credentials, String searchFeilds, String resultFeildNames,
            String managerAttribute) throws Exception {
        InitialLdapContext adminContext = null;

        try {
            ArrayList<SearchResult> result = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();
            Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
            connectionProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", initial);
            connectionProperties.put("java.naming.provider.url", url);
            connectionProperties.put("java.naming.referral", "ignore");
            connectionProperties.put("java.naming.security.principal", principal);
            connectionProperties.put("java.naming.security.credentials", credentials);
            connectionProperties.put("javax.security.sasl.maxbuffer", 2000000);

            adminContext = new InitialLdapContext(connectionProperties, null);

            String filter;
            filter = "(&(userstatus=active)(|(" + managerAttribute + "=" + accountName + ")(CN=" + accountName + ")))";
            String searchFeildsArray[] = searchFeilds.split(",");
            String resultFeildNamesArray[] = resultFeildNames.split(",");

            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answers = null;
            //
            ArrayList<ValueCollection> values = new ArrayList<ValueCollection>();

            try {
                String baseDn = "ou=accounts"; // TODO: Change me
                answers = adminContext.search(baseDn, filter, getSearchControlsForFetchUser(searchFeilds));
                SearchResult userInfo;
                if (!answers.hasMore()) {
                    // throw new Exception("User does not exist in AD");
                    return null;
                }
                try {
                    String Names = "";
                    int count = 0;

                    while (answers.hasMore()) {
                        ValueCollection data = new ValueCollection();
                        userInfo = (SearchResult) answers.next();
                        for (int i = 0; i < searchFeildsArray.length; i++) {
                            Attribute attr = userInfo.getAttributes().get(searchFeildsArray[i]);
                            if (attr != null) {
                                data.put(resultFeildNamesArray[i], new StringPrimitive(attr.get().toString()));
                            }
                        }
                        values.add(data);
                        String temp = userInfo.getAttributes().get("cn").get().toString();

                        if (!temp.equals(accountName)) {
                            Names = Names == "" ? temp : Names + "," + temp;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (Names.length() > 0)
                        values = getData(Names, managerAttribute, adminContext, baseDn, searchFeilds, resultFeildNames,
                                values);
                    return values;
                } catch (PartialResultException var10) {
                    throw new Exception("User does not exist in AD or credentials are invalid");
                }
            } finally {
                if (answers != null) {
                    answers.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (adminContext != null) {
                adminContext.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<ValueCollection> getData(String accountNames, String managerAttribute,
            InitialLdapContext adminContext, String baseDn, String searchFeilds, String resultFeildNames,
            ArrayList<ValueCollection> values) throws Exception {

        String filter = "";
        String[] Names = accountNames.split(",");
        filter = "(&(userstatus=active)(|";
        for (String Name : Names) {
            filter += "(" + managerAttribute + "=" + Name + ")";
        }
        filter += "))";

        String searchFeildsArray[] = searchFeilds.split(",");
        String resultFeildNamesArray[] = resultFeildNames.split(",");
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answers = null;
        // String filter = "(" + managerAttribute + "=" + accountName + ")";
        answers = adminContext.search(baseDn, filter, getSearchControlsForFetchUser(searchFeilds));
        SearchResult userInfo;
        String SearchedUsers = "";
        int count = 0;
        while (answers.hasMore()) {
            ValueCollection data = new ValueCollection();
            userInfo = (SearchResult) answers.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < searchFeildsArray.length; i++) {
                Attribute attr = userInfo.getAttributes().get(searchFeildsArray[i]);
                if (attr != null) {
                    data.put(resultFeildNamesArray[i], new StringPrimitive(attr.get().toString()));
                }
            }
            values.add(data);
            String temp = userInfo.getAttributes().get("cn").get().toString();

            SearchedUsers = SearchedUsers == "" ? temp : SearchedUsers + "," + temp;
            count++;
        }
        if (SearchedUsers.length() > 0)
            values = getData(SearchedUsers, managerAttribute, adminContext, baseDn, searchFeilds, resultFeildNames,
                    values);
        return values;
    }
```

Comment: Which LDAP server are you using?
Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is Dept an organizational unit, and is Manager X a user? Please be more specific. I currently need to make too many assumptions to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @mvreijn  I have updated the question to be more specific on what is required

Comment: @jwilleke I have updated the question to be more specific on what is required and we are  using Microfocus  eDirectory offering LDAP services

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations! You are using the best LDAP server available.

I assume the default attributes are used for the hierarchy: `manager` for a person's manager and `directReports` for their subordinates. These are **DN** attributes, meaning they point directly to an object and you can read them instead of searching for them.

**Case 1: directReports is available**

The `directReports` attribute points downward in the organizational tree.
If the `directReports` attribute is populated, you should proceed as follows:

1. Retrieve the specified user object and retrieve the `directReports` attribute
2. for every value of `directReports` that is returned, read the user object it points to, and retrieve their `directReports` attribute
3. Repeat step 2 for every value of `directReports`

If you store each user while iterating, you will end up with the required list.

**Case 2: only manager is available**

This is a little more work. The `manager` attribute points upwards in the organizational tree. You will have to search for users that have the given user as manager.

1. Retrieve the specified user object and get the DN (via `SearchResult.getNameInNameSpace()`
2. search for users with `(manager=<DN>)` where `<DN>` is the one you just resolved
3. for each result, get the DN and repeat step 2

If you store each user while iterating, you will end up with the required list.

Some more pointers:

- in your `adminContext.search()` the baseDN is either the value from `directReports` (case 1) or the normal base DN (case 2).
- searching for `(manager=<accountname>)` will not yield any results in your example because `<accountname>` is not a DN value (like *cn=accountname,ou=users,o=org*)

Comment: Currently, I am following Case 2 as I don't have directReports attribute available. I am able to receive the output by iterating each level but the issue is if there are more levels it is taking so much time.

Comment: There are some ways to speed it up, but eventually those searches will have to be performed. How long does it take, and how many levels do you have?

Comment: It is taking around 9 seconds for 1 level search for up to 1000 users and if there are more users I need to search again at the same level as I am getting "[LDAP: error code 80 - NDS error: insufficient buffer (-649)];" Error.  So I am doing a split search.
going up the organization the service is taking more time to search

Comment: In this case -649 means the search filter is too large; more than 64k (which is quite a big search filter). However 9 seconds for one search is quite long. To me, this says the search should be optimized, and you need an index on the `manager` attribute

Comment: Yes my filter was too large and will it be possible to increase the size of the filter so it will reduce the number of searches to be done

Comment: The buffer holding the filter is fixed as far as I know. But I fail to see why your filter becomes so large; you are searching for one manager value at at time I would think. When searches take long, you should reduce the number of attributes returned (maybe even return no attributes, only the DN) and create an index: https://www.netiq.com/documentation/edirectory-9/edir_admin/data/a5tuuu5.html