# How to increase buffer space for a Ldap Search in Java

Tags: java, search, filter, ldap

I have written a program in JAVA which does an LDAP search using the given filter and if the filter is too big I am getting insufficient buffer error

```
[LDAP: error code 80 - NDS error: insufficient buffer (-649)];
```

Is there any way to increase the buffer size. I have tried updating buffer size using
`connectionProperties.put("javax.security.sasl.maxbuffer", 2000000);`
but it doesn't work

The code I am using is in this question
[How to improve performance of LDAP Search Filter for User Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69983733/how-to-improve-performance-of-ldap-search-filter-for-user-hierarchy)

Comment: This is not about sasl I think but about (Novell) directory services buffers. It could be that the server is out of available memory (insufficient java heap size, or server is out of RAM). See [error -649](https://www.netiq.com/documentation/edirectory-92/nwec/data/alwxsrr.html#al39nm5) description. The [DSTrace utility](https://www.netiq.com/documentation/edir88/edir88tshoot/data/bq0gvax.html) might help you (I don't know much about it though).

Comment: @EricLavault I have a very big filter searching for more than 1000 users and it's showing the insufficient buffer error and if I reduce the users in search and it's working fine all the time. And there is no issue with the server RAM

Comment: If the buffer size is managed internally by nds, the buffer itself lives either in memory or on directly on storage, so it might be worth a try to monitor and play with the java heap (dictated by RAM), and with ulimits (eg. check for 'too many open files' error in logs, etc.).